# PDO stored procedures with parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

I'm new with SQL stored procedures. All procedures are encrypted so I cannot see the code itself, but I have manual which contains information about parameters.

This stored procedure is made for inserting data to database. It contains lots of parameters e.g. `@orderid` and `@customerid`. While I don't need to use all the parameters, I tried to use following code to insert data with procedure.

```
$sql = $pdowin->query("EXEC salesorderimport @orderid=:orderid, @customerid=:customerid");
$sql->bindValue(':orderid', 000050);
$sql->bindValue(':customerid', 801040);
$sql->execute();
```

It gives me following error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[07002]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error' in ...\test.php:14 Stack trace: #0 ...\test.php(14): PDO->query('EXEC salesorder...') #1 {main} thrown in ...\test.php on line 14

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the error truncated `incorrect or syntax error in...` or is there more to it? Does the procedure expect that you bind output parameters as well as input parameters? The error reported does not look like an error with the way you are calling it (except that you should wrap `'000050'` in quotes to ensure it is passed as a string rather than an octal int)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, just updated the error message. I don't know about the output and input parameters... can't see the sql of procedure.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the SQL Server and simply call this procedure outside the context of PHP/PDO? The error seems more likely to be an error with the procedure itself rather than with PDO calling it, and since you can't see its code, you must at least verify that it works at all.

Comment: @lingo - You need to add the procedure code in question.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, yes I'm able. Error message says that there are parameters which are not supplied. So I think I need to supply all the param values.... ill try

Comment: @VR46, can't add because the procedure is encrypted.